# How to retrieve third_party_id in Facebook's Android 3.x SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I've inherited an app that uses the Facebook third_party_id as part of the user authentication process.  The app currently uses a very old version of the Facebook SDK and I'm attempting to update it to 3.16.  I've found the third_party_id isn't returned as part of the standard newMeRequest call.  after searching around I expected the following call to work (a similar call is reported to work on iOS):

```
Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me?fields=third_party_id", new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        if(response.getError() == null) {
            final String id = (String) response.getGraphObject().asMap().get("third_party_id");
            mUser.setFbAuthenticatorCleartext(id, getApplicationContext());
            mGotThirdPartyFacebookResponse = true;
            ...
```

However, when attempting this approach I see the following error:
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}, isFromCache:false}

I'm already logged in and am able to get the user's email & other public information in a newMeRequest.  It shouldn't be necessary to request additional permissions, but what am I missing?

Comment: I'm looking at the API documentation, and they give an example by instantiating a new `Request` object and then calling it via `.executeAsync()`. They don't show `Request.newGraphPAthRequest` do you think the mechanism you're using is out-dated? See their example here: http://goo.gl/Tkg7nG

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ChitownDev, you got me on the right path.  Here is how I ultimately got it working:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,third_party_id,email");
new Request(session,
    "me",
    params,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if(response.getError() == null) {
                final String id = (String) response.getGraphObject().asMap().get("third_party_id");
                mUser.setFbAuthenticatorCleartext(id, getApplicationContext());
                ...
            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```